# jquery: click callback is called even if button is disabled?

Tags: jquery, button, click

I have this code:

```
// jquery
$(':button').live('click', eventHandler);

<!--html-->
<button type="button" name="lvldown" disabled="disabled">Level down</button>
```

I expected the click event not to be invoked after click if the button is disabled because of this `<button> disabled` [description](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) at w3schools:

> *Definition and Usage*
>
> *The disabled attribute specifies that a button should be disabled.*
>
> *A disabled button is unusable and un-clickable.*

However, my `eventHandler` is still being called after click. Why is that? Do I really need to do something like `$(':button:not([disabled])').live('click', eventHandler);`?

**EDIT:** the problem actually ocurrs only under my chrome 16.0.912.77. Under firefox and IE my code works just fine. Btw. I use jquery 1.7.1. Here are some screenshots:
[the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se8so.png), [console after load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz7vU.png), [console after click on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p3yI.png)

My code now basically looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(':button').live('click', eventHandler);
    constraintActions();
});

function constraintActions() {
    // level down
    $('.shopCat').not('.shopCat[data-parent]').each(function() {
        var lvlDownButton = $(this).children('p').children('[name=lvldown]');

        if ($(this).children('.shopCat').size() > 0 || 
                $(this).next('.shopCat').size() == 0) {
            lvlDownButton.addClass('disabled'); 
            lvlDownButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // also tried: lvlDownButton.prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            lvlDownButton.removeClass('disabled');  
            lvlDownButton.removeAttr('disabled'); //also tried: lvlDownButton.prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });

function eventHandler() {
    console.log($(this));
}
```

**EDIT2:** In fact the button html looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="submit btn-generic" name="lvldown" disabled="disabled">
    <span class="lvldown">Podřadit</span>
</button>
```

I tried to keep just an essence but it seems that I left out something important and that important thing is the span inside because the following works (!) as expected:

```
<button type="button" class="submit btn-generic" name="lvldown" disabled="disabled">
    Podřadit
</button>
```

If i try to add inner span into the examples you provided in the comments, I get these results (under chrome 16.0.912.77):

*Javascript (by j08691):*

```
$('button').live('click', function(){alert('FIRE!')});
```

*Html (by j08691):*

```
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">Level down</button> <!-- does not fire -->
<button type="button" disabled="disabled"><span>Level down</span></button> <!-- does fire!-->
```

*Javascript (by Pointy, jquery is set to version 1.5.2):*

```
$<button disabled>Hi</button>('button').live('click', function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

*Html (by Pointy):*

```
<button disabled>Hi</button> <!-- does not fire -->
<button disabled><span>Hi</span></button> <!-- does not fire -->
<!-- after changing jquery version to 1.7.1 -->
<button disabled><span>Hi</span></button> <!-- does fire! -->
```

Under firefox it does not fire no matter what, just under (my) chrome it behaves like this. Is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

P.S. sorry that my post has become so long

Comment: Show the full code. It's not supposed to happen. something is missing...

Comment: [It works fine for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/xsxYy/)  Maybe the universe is upset with you [for using w3schools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: Doesn't fire for me: http://jsfiddle.net/khRBU/

Comment: update: my code work as expected under firefox and IE, but not under chrome. I use jquery 1.7.1. I have tried your examples with 1.7.1 and they all work under my chrome. This is gonna be funny debugging...(no errors in console).

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is a problem with jQuery < 1.5 and IE (at least IE8). Try [one of the working examples above](http://jsfiddle.net/khRBU) in IE8 and select jQuery 1.4.4 from the dropdown on the left.
To solve this problem try updating the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not have any HTML tags inside a  tag, exception being the  tag which should be avoided anyway and use CSS to get the same effect.

If you are using it to hold a class attribute, you should apply this to the button itself as any formatting applied to the button will be applied to the button content, including text.

It's obvious from your question that your problem stems from the  inside the  so try removing it and applying the class to the actual button.